# How to delay the execution of functions - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im using this to delay and fadeout some messages on my site.

```
<script> $("#infomsg").delay(2400).fadeOut(600);</script>
```

So when page is loaded the message is still on page 2400ms after that is gone with fadeout, but how i can make, when you open page i need this message to display after 3 sec. or simple slow fadein first.. im try something like this

```
<script> $("#infomsg").fadeIn(1200).delay(2400).fadeOut(600);</script>
```

and this not work for me, can you help me to make this ?

P.S
Sorry for my english and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be running this on document load.  Other than that, the only problem I see is a missing period.

```
<script>
   $(function() {
       $("#infomsg").fadeIn(1200)
                    .delay(2400)
                    .fadeOut(600);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Im just try and again all works fine only fadeIn not work.. :(

Comment: @user994461 - does the element start hidden, i.e., have you set `style="display: none;"` on the element or used CSS to hide it initially?  Or, better yet, use `$('#infomsg').hide().fadeIn(1200)...`

Comment: Ohh im forgot for style="display: none;" :(
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use callbacks.

```
$("#infomsg").fadeIn(1200, function() {
  $(this).delay(2400).fadeOut(600);
});
```

so...

- fadeIn
- wait for 2400 after fadeIn
- fadeOut

Comment: No you don't.  Look at the example in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: @tvanfosson - correct, you can certainly chain them too. It just sounded like user994461 wanted to do additional things.

Answer (score 0):

$("#infomsg").fadeIn(1200).delay(2400).fadeOut(600); 
you miss a dot